# JSON Arrays and Google Charts

Tags: json, ajax, google-visualization

I have a JSON feed of two arrays and I am struggling to get it to show the chart. I am trying to display a multi series chart.I cannot get my head around it.

```
{
"Protein": [{
    "Count": 2,
    "Day": "Friday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}, {
    "Count": 3,
    "Day": "Monday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}, {
    "Count": 2,
    "Day": "Saturday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}, {
    "Count": 1,
    "Day": "Sunday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}, {
    "Count": 3,
    "Day": "Thursday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}, {
    "Count": 2,
    "Day": "Tuesday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}, {
    "Count": 2,
    "Day": "Wednesday",
    "Type": "Protein"
}],
"Hec": [{
    "Count": 2,
    "Day": "Friday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}, {
    "Count": 3,
    "Day": "Monday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}, {
    "Count": 1,
    "Day": "Saturday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}, {
    "Count": 1,
    "Day": "Sunday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}, {
    "Count": 1,
    "Day": "Thursday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}, {
    "Count": 1,
    "Day": "Tuesday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}, {
    "Count": 2,
    "Day": "Wednesday",
    "Type": "HEC"
}]
}
```

How do I loop through these in the Ajax call in Google charts. I have added the JS here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orangegoblin/9YCTL/2221/)

I have been checking console in Chrome and i can see the JSON coming through. When I try to iterate and add.Rows, it tells me that it data.addROw is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to JSON, it took me a little while to work it out. But here is my answer to add multiple series from JSON to Google Charts (the way my JSON feed is formatted above).

```
 success: function (d) {        
               data.addColumn('string', 'Day');                 

               for (j = 0; j < Object.keys(d).length; j++) {                      
                   data.addColumn('number', Object.keys(d)[j]);                         
               };

               for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
                   data.addRow([d.Protein[i].Day, d.Protein[i].Count, d.Hec[i].Count, d.Lec[i].Count, d.F[i].Count]);
               };
            }
```

I have tested it by adding new keys to the JSON and it updates automatically and shows the four series on the chart. There was an issue with null values, but I have resolved this in the DB, by adding all days of the week for all of the series, such that, there will always be seven days in a week.

Answer (score 0):

I see this line in your Fiddle code:

```
success: function(data) {
```

What is happening is that the data defined in this function is overwriting the data that you defined earlier for the dataTable. So data in this context is actually referring to the AJAX response data, not the data table. You should either give the success callback a different variable name for the data or change the variable name of the data table so that the 2 don't collide.

Comment: also need to move `chart.draw` inside the `success` callback, otherwise, it will run before the data is loaded...

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for that, I was able to get one series into the chart. So I have added a nested loop to add the columns. I get the columns added, but I cannot get the data to add the rows. I have updated the Fiddle to show the loop.  Any pointers would be very helpful...